# animations doesn't work when I add bootstrap4 cdn

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/9JpsWBPgRtBDOYE6QB/source.gif" style="width:100%; height: 100%; border-radius: 0; ">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="https://media2.giphy.com/media/fRGq1cnopavJ7mKDYn/giphy.webp" style="width:100%; height: 100%; border-radius: 0; ">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/lPRrCc9lQsOPa2qZiw/giphy.webp" style="width:100%; height: 100%; border-radius: 0; ">
   </div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(+1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
  <div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
    

<script>
    
    var slideIndex = 1;
    var timer = null;
    showSlides(slideIndex);
    
    function plusSlides(n) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }
    
    function currentSlide(n) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }
    
    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
      if (n==undefined){n = ++slideIndex}
      if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
          dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
      dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
      timer = setTimeout(showSlides, 2500);
    } 
    </script>
```

This is my slider image with button and auto slide. I got this code from w3schools and edited.Some of the codes are not good but the main problem is when I add Bootstrap4 CDN it is not working and some of the divs(class "container") are getting smaller. How can I solve this.

Comment: Please keep in mind that BS4 has their own slider. Maybe it has some conflict with Javascript. I suggest to use https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/carousel/
Just in case, add your current html code also in order to complete our answer

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite this bootstrap CSS

`.fade:not(.show) { opacity: 1; }`

Full Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
        .fade:not(.show){
            opacity: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/9JpsWBPgRtBDOYE6QB/source.gif" style="width:100%; height: 100%; border-radius: 0 ">
        </div>
      
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="https://media2.giphy.com/media/fRGq1cnopavJ7mKDYn/giphy.webp" style="width:100%; height: 100%; border-radius: 0 ">
        </div>
      
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/lPRrCc9lQsOPa2qZiw/giphy.webp" style="width:100%; height: 100%; border-radius: 0 ">
         </div>
      
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(+1)">&#10095;</a>
      
    </div>


    <div style="text-align:center">
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
    </div>
          
      
      <script>
          
          var slideIndex = 1;
          var timer = null;
          showSlides(slideIndex);
          
          function plusSlides(n) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            showSlides(slideIndex += n);
          }
          
          function currentSlide(n) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            showSlides(slideIndex = n);
          }
          
          function showSlides(n) {
            var i;
            var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
            var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
            if (n==undefined){n = ++slideIndex}
            if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
            if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
            for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                slides[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
            dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
            timer = setTimeout(showSlides, 2500);
          } 
          </script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```